# Angular nested components repeated in different views

Tags: angularjs

I am working with Angular 1.5 and angular new router (component router), but I believe this question applies to Angular 2 as well.

If I have a toolbar that is always visible (regardless of what view/ route I'm on) but it's contents change, what is the correct approach:

Create multiple toolbars, one for each "view" (even though the toolbar wrapper is the same html)  OR
Is there a way to do something like the following and somehow "inject" or otherwise specify what fields and buttons will appear in the toolbar:

```
<body>
    <app>
        <app-header>
            <!-- logo, username, etc. -->
        </app-header>
        <toolbar>
            <filters>
                <!-- such as search, etc. -->
            </filters>
            <actions>
                <!-- such as "create new" button, etc. -->
            </actions>
        </toolbar>
        <view-one>
            <!-- content -->
        </view-one>
        <view-two>
            <!-- content -->
        </view-two>
    </app>
</body>
```

- every toolbar has `<filters>` and `<actions>`, each of which has it's own html but the buttons/ fields residing within change per "view".
- I realize that in a real app some of the above tags would only be included in their respective components and not in the main html.

Comment: create a service that checks the state and in each controller build an array that populates a factory that it shares with the header. this is probably the best way.

Comment: I would say: 3 views - one template with ng-if's. 5 views - several different templates. 10 views+ - some toolbar component, which gets button list from some service or similar.